# Searching for the files which have search terms in python

Tags: python, parsing, search, text

Trying to find search word in a bunch of text document in a folder using that approach:

```
dirname = '/Users/user/Documents/dat/'
search_terms = ['kek']

for f in os.listdir(dirname):

    text = open(os.path.join(dirname,f)).readlines() 

    if any(term in text for term in search_terms):

        print (f)
```

For some reason, don't know why, it gives me the name of first file in directory no matter consists it this search term or not. What should be done differently to proper do this task?

Thanks!

Comment: try `text = file.read()  
if "kek" in text`  then print what you need to print

Comment: You'd need something like `for line in text: found = any(term in line for term in search_terms)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you need.

```
dirname = '/Users/user/Documents/dat/'
search_terms = ['kek']

for f in os.listdir(dirname):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname,f), "r") as infile:
        text =  infile.read()

    if any(term in text for term in search_terms):
        print (f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you find the right term in the file, you aren't printing the term, you're printing the file name, f.

Try:

```
    for line in text:
        if any(term in line for term in search_terms):
            print(line)
```

Also, don't forget to either close your file when you're done with it, or use [with](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)